# Login and register form, can be reused to do?

Tags: reactjs

In the case of a membership registration form with one more input added, I would like to reuse the form element. Is it possible?

I think we need to define the marking part of the third code, but I don't know how.

Is there a better way than this?

```js
export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form inputData={INPUT_DATA} page="login" />
    </div>
  );
}

const INPUT_DATA = [
  { name: 'email', type: 'text', placeholder: 'email' },
  { name: 'password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'password' },
];
```

```js
export default function RegisterPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form inputData={INPUT_DATA} page="register" />
    </div>
  );
}
const INPUT_DATA = [
  { name: 'email', type: 'text', placeholder: 'email' },
  { name: 'password', type: 'password', placeholder: 'password' },
  { name: 'confirmPassword', type: 'password', placeholder: 'confirm password' },
];
```

```js
export default function Form ({inputData,page}) {
  const [info,setInfo] = useState({
    login:{
      email:'',
      password:''    
    },
    register:{
      email:'',
      password:'',
      confirmPassword:''
      }
  });

  const onChange = (e, page) => {
    setUserInfo((state) => ({
      ...state, 
      state[page]: {...state[page],{????:e.target.value}}
    }))
  }     {/* <---------1st */}
    return (
        <form>
          {inputData.map((data) => (
            <input
              key={data.name}
              type={data.type}
              name={data.name}
              placeholder={data.placeholder} 
              value={`${userInfo[page]}.${data.name}`} {/* <---------2nd */}
              onChange={()=>onChange(e,page)}
              />
          ))}
          <button type="submit">{page === 'login' ? 'login': 'register'}</button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Comment: Use the `inputData` you have defined. In your `Form` component you aren't using it and importing `INPUT_DATA` directly

Comment: @Andrew I don't know.
I'm sorry, but could you explain it with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use your prop value in your `Form` component instead of hard coding the array

```
{inputData.map((data) => (
<input
    key={data.name}
    type={data.type}
    name={data.name}
    placeholder={data.placeholder} 
    value={`${userInfo[page]}.${data.name}`} {/* <---------2nd */}
    onChange={()=>onChange(e,page)}
    />
))}
```

Comment: Oh, I must have written the wrong code It is right to get inputDate as above by map. But I don't know how to give the value and setState function over there.

Comment: Data should be managed by the parent then. Put your `useState` in the parent and pass it down